caching by input length
I have a function that takes an input array & performs some expensive operation.
The solution's runtime degrades with input size & because the function is often called with identical sub-arrays, I am looking for a caching strategy that only stores the longest input arrays & kicks out the shorter (least expensive) results.
I really love the cache-tools package with their LRUCache & similar strategies but I am not clear how to combine existing or extend our own.
